# Conda package cannot be installed into the PyCharm virtual environment?

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, conda

The attempt to install the conda package from File-->Settings-->Python Interpreter becomes unsuccessful. The following was the output

The message from PyCharm is

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement menuinst (from conda) (from versions: none)

try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '<UserName>\Pycharm\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe'.
```

The output of

```
 <UserName>\PyCharm\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip --version
```

is `pip 20.2.4`. The pip version in PyCharm interpreter settings is also pip 20.2.4

When I first tried to import numpy by just typing `import numpy as np` , PyCharm was not successful in installing numpy and gave the message to install using pip from the terminal, installing from the terminal was not successful either. Then Numpy was installed from the Python Interpreter Settings at File-->Settings. Afterwards, before getting NumPy installed, PyCharm even became unable to detect the import statement and to offer to install NumPy

- How would Scientific mode be enabled for the current project given that the conda interpreter is not installed?.
  How to get the conda package(interpreter) installed from within PyCharm
- What is the defect that prevented PYcharm from detecting the import statement in the editor
  and giving the message "No module named numpy" with the offer to install NumPy.
- What is the reason causing the pip error?

Comment: In PyCharm are you using a global or a virtual environment? You can also install packages into a correct location straight from PyCharm. Just go to Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter and then on the right pane click the "+" button which will take you to package install. Search for numpy in serach box and install it from there.

Comment: the module name is `numpy` not `numPy`. Scientific mode is only for professional or educational version. And try to get good habit from beginning, about names. `PyCharm` is a bad name for a directory (it is just a tool). `pythonProject` is also a bad name. If you start with lazy names, you will get soon problems (and it is a bad habit to remove, and it is very bad seen in professional environment)

Comment: Are you using Conda? The file path is for a venv environment, no

Comment: conda is a tool, not a package, it should be installed separately from https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html or https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/ (I'd recommend miniconda)